# How to check if the determinant of (A*lambda*I) = 0 of a matrix in python?

Tags: python, math, matrix

For this problem I have created an 8x8 array in python and found the eigenvalues and eigenfrequencies using numpy's linalg tool. However, now I need to verify that these eigenvalues are correct by checking if det(A-lambda*I) = 0, where A is the 8x8 array, I is the identity matrix, and then lambda. How would I go about solving this in python? Is there a tool in numpy that would allow me to do this easily? I've included my code up to finding the identity matrix.

```
#Defining an 8x8 matrix using random numbers
A = np.zeros((8, 8), dtype=complex)
A[1::2,::2] = 1
A[::2,1::2] = 1

eig_vals, eig_vecs = np.linalg.eig(A)

print("The resulting eigenvalues of the 8x8 matrix is:", eig_vals)
print("The resulting eigenvectors of the 8x8 matrix is:", eig_vecs)


I = np.identity(8)
```

Comment: Why do you need to verify that the eigenvalues are correct? Unless there is a bug in numpy, it will be zero, no need to test.

Comment: @Gilles-PhilippePaillé I dunno, checking results is always good practice. Checking might or might not uncover a bug in a library, but it will always confirm that the caller is asking the question that they think they're asking.

Comment: @RobertDodier It's true that it's good practice, but unless I suspect a bug, I think it's too much time lost to write unit tests for external libraries. But I agree that it confirms that you really got what you expected.

Comment: We're expected to confirm numpy's results via a different method. More than one way to skin a pig, I guess.

Comment: @ked123 It totally makes sense as part of an assignment, I was just curious. Note that you can also check the result by checking that `A*e = l*e`, where `e` is an eigenvector and `l` is its corresponding eigenvalue. It is faster to compute than computing the determinant of an 8x8 matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about simply:

```
for i in range(len(eig_vals)):
    print(np.linalg.det(A - eig_vals[i]*I))
```

?

Of course you need to take numerical error into account - they are not exact zeros, but look close enough :)